How many Tverberg partition are in cloud of points?
Tverberg's Theorem: A collection of $(d+1)(r-1) +1$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can always be partitioned into $r$ parts whose convex hulls  intersect.
For example, $d=2$, $r=3$, 7 points:

Let $p_1, p_2,\dotsc, p_{d+1}\in \mathbb{R}^d$ form the vertices ofa  simplex. Let $q$ be the center of the simplex (i.e. $q=(p_1+ p_2+\dotsb+ p_{d+1})/(d+1)$). Replace each $p_i$ by a tiny cloud of $r-1$ points.
My question is how many Tverberg partition are there? And what are they?

For example:

Here, $d=2, r=5, n=13$ points by Tverberg Theorem. So there are $r=5$ parts, $13$ points into $5$ parts, $4$ triangles and a center point. So, how many different ways we can do that? $4^3.3^3.2^3.1^3/4!=4!^2,$ because partition order doesn't matter.

In general, we have $d+1$ clouds, and $r-1$ simplicies. In each cloud we have $r-1$ points. The number of ways to choose first simplex is $(r-1)^{d+1}.$
So exact number of Tverberg partition is $$\frac{(r-1)^{d+1}.(r-2)^{d+1}\ldots 1^{d+1}}{(r-1)!}=(r-1)!^d.$$

The answer depends on the clouds. Are you interested in the maximum/minimum?

Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947932/number-of-tverberg-partitions

After warnings on this site and the other, the question is still ill-phrased, though the OP does not seem to acknowledge this and claims to have found a solution, which is incorrect, also nothing has been done about cross-posting, so I'm voting to close.
